# Adding multiple byte arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, binary, byte

I'm working on a legacy system that uses byte arrays for permission levels.
Example:
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 means they have "Full Control"
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 means they have "Add Control"
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 means they have "Delete Control"

So, if a User has "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07" that means they have all 3 (as far as it has been explained to me).

Now, my question is that I need to know how to get to "0x07" when creating/checking records.
I don't know the syntax for actually combining 0x01, 0x02 and 0x04 so that I come out with 0x07.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You OR them together:

```
0x01 | 0x02 | 0x04 == 0x07
```

If you want to examine the individual bits in candidate byte `b`:

```
Full Control   == b & 0x01
Add Control    == b & 0x02
Delete Control == b & 0x04
```

Comment: I'm working with an array of bytes.  Based on the system, all I know is that there will be 8, but I don't know what location those bytes will be in.  I may have to combine "0x01 0x10" with "0x04 0x00" to come up with "0x05 0x10".  I tried using the `|` operator on the array of bytes and I'm told it can't be used.

Comment: Well, how do you figure out which locations the bytes are in?  They're greater than zero?  No, you can't OR the whole thing, but you can OR the individual bytes.

Comment: I took what you said and just did a quick for loop for all 8 bytes in the array to get out what I want.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The OR opeerator is what you're looking for.

IMO, a clean way to handle it would be to use an enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum Permisions
{
    FullControl = 0x1,
    AddControl = 0x2,
    DeleteControl = 0x4
}
```

Then, in your code you can do things like:

```
Permissions userPermissions = Permissions.AddControl | Permissions.DeleteControl;
bool canDelete = userPermissions.HasFlag(Permissions.DeleteControl);
```

Comment: As I said above, I'm working with an array of bytes.  The `|` operator doesn't work on them.  I suppose I can go through each byte in the array.

Comment: How do you determine which byte contains the permission you're looking for? I mean, I'm assuming byte[0] would hold the permission for controlling one object type, and byte[1] would hold the permission for controlling another, and so on. You'd be checking against whichever byte is associated with what you're trying to do. So you'd just do userPermissions[index] | Permissions.AddControl;

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert 8-bytes arrays into ulong array using [`BitConverter.ToUInt64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint64.aspx). After that you'll be able to use regular bitwise operations on those ulongs and convert the result back to byte array using [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8z32tce.aspx) if necessary.

You might want to implement a tiny wrapper for this, if you have to deal with permissions repeatedly.